# echo function call 2 variables

Tags: php, function, url, get, echo

Ok so I have the code for a form that is called and works but it needs two varibles grabbed from the string of a url.  I have the first and the second is the same for what im doing on any page that I am creating which is alot.  Here is the code at the url: collabedit.com/9g99j

Question if Get `<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>` is grabbing my id string from the url how do I use this in the echo of my function I just defined at the bottom of the code?  Instead of having this: `echo DescriptionGet(1256124, 50874);` can someone tell me how to put something like this: `echo DescriptionGet(1256124, $id);`

This would make it so i dont' have to enter that id value for every page I want to create.

Thanks,

Thanks everyone for your replies and I was able to figure it out on my own and actually used exactly what the first reply was.

Now I have a new question about this function.  How do I make it grab the image from that same page its grabbing the form code from?  I can't figure this part out and its keeping me from doing mass automation for this site.

Anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function definition from:

```
function DescriptionGet($c, $id)
```

to

```
function DescriptionGet($c, $id=50874)
```

Each time when you will call `DescriptionGet($c)` it will behave as you passed `$id=50874` but also if you need you can call `DescriptionGet($c, 20)` and $id in the function will be set to 20.

And in case you want to simple use `$_GET['id']` as function parameter you can simple run

```
echo DescriptionGet(1256124, intval($_GET['id']));
```

you don't even need to use extra variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo DescriptionGet(1256124, $id);
```